# Delete permissions from site with powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

I know how to delete permissions from lists and document libraries. Simply I can use the `BreakRoleInheritance`, and I can remove every user. But I couldn't find a way to do this with a site.

Like this: `$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite (http://spt/spaces/thisisit)`

`$site` doesn't have inheritance method (or I just don't know how to use it).

So how can I delete every permission on a site? Not on the lists, not on the document libraries, but on the site itself?

Comment: I really recommend you to read up on the differences between site collections, and sites in SharePoint (hence SPSite and SPWeb objects) as well as the basic security features of SP. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/getting-my-head-round-spsite-vs-spweb-vs-anything-else for SPWeb vs SPSite, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262939(v=office.14).aspx for permissions and security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the web object of the site to break the inheritance:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
$web.BreakRoleInheritance($True)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to delete permission levels in root web, you can do it this way:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010:90
$PermissionLevel=$web.RoleDefinitions
$PermissionLevel.Delete("Contribute")
```

Comment: This seems to be the way. But i got an error: "Cannot change permissions of root web:
I am the owner with full control. Why can't i modify it?

Comment: The error is obvious, you break inheritance for child webs not root web. Rootweb doesn't inherit from anything.

Comment: Hmmm. I thought the stp is the root web. But the "thisisit" is also root? 
Because then i have an another problem. How can i delete every user on root web?